# Dialogflow - Unable to access microphone

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Im using Dialogflow to create something cool, but every time I hit the "try it out" button it replies unable to access your microphone. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong and give me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Is this using the Actions on Google simulator or something else? Updating your question to include screen shots of what you are trying, what browser you're trying to do this with, and as many other details as possible, can increase the chance of us being able to help you.

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Im using a MacBook Pro, im on safari... I'm extremely new at this stuff so if anyone would like to give me tips too that would be cool but im just trying to make an agent which allows me to talk to it and it gives me feedback like Jarvis from iron man.

Comment: Again - trying to understand, especially since someone has changed the tags and its not clear if they were changed correctly. What are you running in Safari? Are you trying to use the Actions on Google simulator when you had this problem? Or are you trying to use something else with dialogflow? You say "make an agent" - are you trying to build something that has the Google Assistant built into it, or build an app *for* the Assistant? The more you can explain in your question, the better chance we have of being able to point you in the right direction.